# Determine matrix's $2\times 2$ second row so that it has given eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If first row of 2x2 matrix is `[2 6]` and eigenvectors are `x1=(3,1)`, `x2=(2,1)` how could I determine the second row of matrix?

Comment: What do you know about eigenvectors?

Comment: I know their values, nothing more

Comment: No no, I mean in general. What is the definition of an eigenvector?

Comment: sorry, I'm beginner in linear algebra, definition is standard, the process of calculating is the same as in all online calculators with steps, for example --> https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-algebra/matrix-calculator/

Comment: could someone explain in answer the process of calculating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're given:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 6\\
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
12\\
3a + b
\end{bmatrix} = \lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 6\\
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
10\\
2a + b
\end{bmatrix} = \lambda_2\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
This means:
$$\lambda_1 = 4, \>\> \lambda_2 = 5$$
So then you have the following set of linear equations:

$$
   \lambda_1 = 3a + b = 4\\
   \lambda_2 = 2a + b = 5
$$
Which gives us $ a = -1$ and $b = 7$.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @devec No worries! If you found it helpful, upvote the answer for visibility.

Comment: I'm new contributor, so I can't upvote jet